# How I can fix this error IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, string

I got IndexError: string index out of range error.

```
def get_int_arr(str):
    int_arr = []
    num_str = ""
    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i].isnumeric():
            num_str += str[i]
            if not str[i+1].isnumeric():
                int_arr.append(num_str)
                num_str = ""
    return int_arr
print(get_int_arr("data 48 call 9 read13 blank0"))
```

Comment: With `str[i+1]` you try to access the position after the last one.

Comment: when Im using for i in range(len(str)-1) I'm not geeting 0 in my output, I'm only getting:['48', '9', '13']

Comment: Can you show the full code for this? As it stands, this is not executable. Also, it looks like you may have overridden the built-in *str* function. That's not good practice

Comment: you can check the length of the list in the second if statement : `if (len(str) > i+1) and not str[i+1].isnumeric():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just append if the last character is numeric and not check the next one.

```py
def get_int_arr(str):
    int_arr = []
    num_str = ""
    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i].isnumeric():
            num_str += str[i]
            if i + 1 == len(str) or not str[i + 1].isnumeric():
                int_arr.append(num_str)
                num_str = ""
    return int_arr
```

Also, the snippet you posted above is not complete (it misses the first line of your function definition I guess) and using reserved keywords like `str` to name your variables/arguments is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it seems that you want a list of all digits found in the string passed to get_int_arr. If that is the case then:

```
def get_int_arr(s):
    return [c for c in s if c.isdigit()]


print(get_int_arr("data 48 call 9 read13 blank0"))
```

...will emit:

['4', '8', '9', '1', '3', '0']

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you add a space at the end of `str` and change `for i in range(len(str)):` to `for i in range(len(str)-1):`

```
def get_int_arr(str):
    int_arr = []
    num_str = ""
    str+=" " #Adding a space at the end of the string
    for i in range(len(str)-1):
        if str[i].isnumeric():
            num_str += str[i]
            if not str[i+1].isnumeric():
                int_arr.append(num_str)
                num_str = ""
    return int_arr
print(get_int_arr("data 48 call 9 read13 blank0"))

#Output: ['48', '9', '13', '0']
```